# Managing transactions in JavaSE with Hibernate and Guice

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, guice

I'm writing a rather simple application that uses GWT, Hibernate and Google Guice (with GIN). What I wanted to do is to have transactions managed using external manager (like using  `@Transactional` in Spring), instead of using `EntityManager#getTransaction`. I tried using `@Transactional`, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I have EntityManager already injected using `Providers`, like this:

```
/* import stuff */

public class DbProvider implements Provider<EntityManager> {

    public EntityManager get() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persdb");
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

It seems to work properly when managing the transactions manually. I wanted to have transactions managed automatically, also for making the automated test with DBUnit.

Does anyone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having `@Transactional` work in Guice [requires three things](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Transactions):

- You need `guice-persist.jar` in your classpath
- The object on which the `@Transactional` methods are called must be created by Guice
- The methods must not be `private`

Comment: thanks a lot! if only that worked:)

where do you start the PersistService?

Comment: @halish: You can start a `PersistService` wherever you want (when your application starts, say). In a web application, it can be done with `PersistFilter`, which starts the service when it's created and stops it when destroyed. In your own application, you need to start it before you do anything that uses it.